# Creating input node file for v.net.salesman in GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, polyline-creation, shortest-path, travelling-salesman

[image]

I have imported the line vector layer and point vector layer (12 points) to GRASS using `v.in.ogr`. Now I want to use `v.in.salesman` to find the shortest path between these 12 points, but I couldn't input anything in the "Input nodes" field.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, before using `v.net.salesman` to get your route, you should connect your points layer to your network (line vector layer) using `v.net` op=connect [1] at nlayer=2

Once you connect your 12 points to your network as nodes, you'll be able to select your nodes layer from the "input nodes" dropdown menu.

- http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.net.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, like @Taras explains, I had to make that step with "v.net" algorithm.

This my own question that I solved by myself and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445422/v-net-salesman-problem-filling-in-dialog-box-parameters/446189#446189) I explains step by step how I solved my problem with "v.in.salesman" algorithm.

I hope it could be useful for you.