# Travelling salesman problem in QGIS using GRASS

Tags: qgis, polyline-creation, qgis-grass-plugin, travelling-salesman

I would like to use the travelling salesman algorithm in the GRASS plugin in QGIS. I have a points layer (3 points) and a road layer. I have connected the 2 together using `v.net`.

and I am given this:

[image]

and it looks like this:

[image]

but when I open up the window for v.net. salesman only the new Network layer is there in the dropdown tab, not the nodes or lines.

Any suggest on where I went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153475/creating-input-node-file-for-v-net-salesman-in-grass