# Drawing the most efficient path between multiple points

Tags: qgis, travelling-salesman

I am trying to find the most efficient path between multiple points on a map.

A bit of background to help understand what I need. I am making a printed map that has LEDs poked through from behind and each LED has a wire 10cm between the next. I am trying to use as many LEDs as possible and minimise wasted LEDs left behind the map.

I have all the points as coordinates in QGIS.

Is there a way to have QGIS draw a line of maximum "10cm" or just a most efficient path between all the points?

Comment: Your problem is not new, but that does not mean it is an easy task at all: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: have a look to this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153475/creating-input-node-file-for-v-net-salesman-in-grass

Comment: Thank you for putting a name to the problem I am facing. It should help a lot with my Google searches.

I came across the TSP plugin but it is way out of date and can't be installed in 3.16

Also, I'm not really good with scripts which complicates things a little

Comment: I guess the GRASS command https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.salesman.html will do the work, but I am aware that GRASS is not the most fliendly software. I suggest you to try it from the processing toolbox in QGIS

Comment: Ok so I have now created a vector layer with a line from each point to every other point with the Beeline plugin.

Now I have gone into v.net.salesman and it isn't really finding a route and I'm getting confused with what I need to input to the fields

Here's what shows up   
https://i.imgur.com/Y2h3DGg.png

Comment: I have been able to get it to work... kinda

I ended up keeping my route network that I created between all points but now imported a cut down version of my points so there is only 6 of them but when I use salesman it won't find a direct routing between the points and prefers to take a few turns.

Here's a pic of what it is doing 

https://i.imgur.com/HKNYC5M.png

Each of those points have a direct line between each of them so it shouldn't be turning at all